# Problems with JSONP and FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, jsonp, fullcalendar

Attempting to use JSONP with FullCalendar, but getting no data when request is being made.
Have set:

```
$.getJSON("http://test:81/calendarJSON.ashx?callback=?"
function(data){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: data
});
        });
```

Request from web page to ashx service is formatted:

```
http://test:81/calendarJSON.ashx?callback=jQuery110208227056053001434_1401204018064&_=1401204018065
```

Not sure if the request is correct.  I thought I would see the start/end time parameters in here is as well.  The response i get from the web service is:

```
jQuery110208227056053001434_1401204018064([])
```

I assume there should be additional parameters being passed which is why i do not get the dataset passed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without sharing `calendarJSON.ashx`'s definition or expectations, it's not really possible to say. In general, at least, the request appears valid -- the URL is well-formed (after jQuery's substitution of `?`) and JSONP allows cross-origin. But, all that's known is the service is responding with an empty collection, `[]`.

Comment: calendarJSON.ashx is expecting a start and end parameter in the query string.  If I supply a request such as:

    http://test:81/calendarJSON.ashx?callback=?&start=1398571200&end=1402200000

the JSONP request works.

So how do i pass the start/end times to the query string?

Answer (score 0):

> *So how do i pass the start/end times to the query string?*

They could be included in the `url` after the 1st `?`, along with `callback=?`:

```
$.getJSON("http://test:81/calendarJSON.ashx?callback=?&start=1398571200&end=1402200000",
// ...
```

Or, with `GET` requests, query-string parameters can be specified as `data`. For [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), that would be the optional 2nd argument:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
```

```
$.getJSON("http://test:81/calendarJSON.ashx?callback=?",
    {
        start: 1398571200,
        end: 1402200000
    },
    function (data) {
        // ...
    }
);
```